# Series Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the series expansion of ln(1+e^(-z)) when z is very large.

I figured this out for when z is very small but I am unsure what to do if z is very large. I think if I just get a hint about that I can figure the rest out.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: When $z$ is very large, the exponential $e^{-z}$ is close to $0$, hence you can use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1 + x)$ when $x$ is near $0$.

Comment: you're welcome, I glad I could help :D